# Xcode, The given data was not valid JSON, Can't read the JSON from API properly

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, api

Hello I am creating an app with Xcode and I am having the following problem, I created this API (if you enter the link you'll see the JSON data) https://proyecto-idts6.epizy.com/models/getCategorias.php

If you dont want to enter the link here is how this si how the structure of the JSON looks like:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "categorie":"Fruits",
         "id_categorie":"1"
      },
      {
         "categorie":"Animals",
         "id_categorie":"2"
      },
      {
         "categorie":"Juices",
         "id_categorie":"3"
      },
      {
         "categorie":"Vegetables",
         "id_categorie":"4"
      },
      {
         "categorie":"Alcohol",
         "id_categorie":"5"
      },
      {
         "categorie":"Desserts",
         "id_categorie":"6"
      }
   ]
}
```

The problem I have is that when I try to decode the data from the API it cant't be decoded properly, I am trying to recreate the same code of this youtube video, but with my API: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqo844saoC4

What I want basically is to print the categories and storage each of them in variables (because i'll need to move the variables between screens)

This is how my code looks like:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = "https://proyecto-idts6.epizy.com/models/getCategorias.php"
        getData(from: url)
        //Here is where i want to storage the variables from the JSON
    }
    private func getData(from url: String) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("something went wrong")
                return
            }
            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([ResultItem].self, from: data)
                print(result)
            }
            catch {
                print("failed to convert\(error)")
            }
        })
            task.resume()
    }
}
struct Response: Codable {
    let items: [ResultItem]
}
struct ResultItem: Codable {
    let categorie: String
}
```

My goal is to have variables for example like this: categorie1=("the category 1 called from the JSON"), categorie2=("the category 2 called from the JSON"), categorie3=("the category 3 called from the JSON"),...

Comment: What's the full output of `print("failed to convert\(error)")`? Could you print also, in that `catch`: `print("Response Stringified: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`, and `print("HTTPResponse: \(response)")`?

Comment: You have a struct `Response` so use it when decoding. You always needs to start at the top level when decoding json.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i did that and when i execute it shows this in the terminal:

convertdataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))

Comment: @Larme the full output is: Failed to log metrics
failed to convertdataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))

Comment: And what about the other prints? It seems that it's returning not only JSON, but either JS that will output JSON, or HTML string with JSON. So please, what's the output of the two other prints? That would explain the decoding error, since it's not returning directly JSON...

Comment: @Larme When I try to execute the HTTPResponse print it says: "Expected member name or constructor call after type" AND when I try to execute the Stringfield print it says: "Undeterminated string literal"

Comment: It's because it's missing a parenthesis: `print("Response Stringified: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")`...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the decoding but in the remote API.

Your endpoint (https://proyecto-idts6.epizy.com/models/getCategorias.php) instead of returning a JSON is returning the following HTML

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("f5490e280a5e50f74932909856c3d3a3");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="https://proyecto-idts6.epizy.com/models/getCategorias.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

So you are trying to decode that HTML content, which clearly leads to the error your reported

```
failed to convertdataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))
```

Comment: When I open the source code of the page when I enter the link of my API (https://proyecto-idts6.epizy.com/models/getCategorias.php) It shows me this (using chrome): <html><head></head><body>{"items":[{"categorie":"Fruits","id_categorie":"1"},{"categorie":"Animals","id_categorie":"2"},{"categorie":"Juices","id_categorie":"3"},{"categorie":"Vegetables","id_categorie":"4"},{"categorie":"Alcohol","id_categorie":"5"},{"categorie":"Desserts","id_categorie":"6"}]}</body></html>